# MMORPG Server Receiving Architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a game server in Node.js, so the question is the architecture of receiving data from the client. Which would be recommended?

1. Using `Node.JS` Net module:

   ```
   server.on('data', function(data) {
     // handle the data
   })
   ```
2. Using a queue system to receive and process the queue? (0mq, RabbitMQ...)

I mean isn't Node.JS' event wheel a queue? So the `net` module is already a queue?

Comment: Hmm. How can #1 and #2 be compared? #2 might layer on #1, but it doesn't work at the same level, nor does #1 provide many of the features of #2.

Comment: So #2 would be the go to for easier development?

Comment: Such questions are related to the scale/scope/design of said MMORPG..

Comment: Multiple servers, like gate server, zone server, auth server. but client only connects to gate server. and around 5000 simultaneous users.